# Mac - Write Cronjob to delete CoreSimulator logs

Tags: macos, logging, cron, delete-file

On a Mac, I'm finding that my Core Simulator logs get very large and reguarly need clearing; I wish to write a cronjob which runs once a week to delete a week's old files from a directory.

`/users/Me/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator`

I believe this directory requires permissions.

I can do basic cronjobs, but I'm not sure about stuff when it comes to permissions.

How would I write a cronjob for this task that may require permissions to delete files from a given directory.

Many thanks